# Django: What is `sys.path` supposed to be?

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

When developing a Django application, what is `sys.path` supposed to contain? The directory which contains the project, or the directory of the project, or both?

Answer (score 3):

`sys.path` should and will have the directory of the project. Depending on what your setup is, it may also contain the directory which contains the project.

However, if the motivation behind this question is to ensure that certain files can be found, then you should note that `sys.path` is just like a normal list and can be appended to. Therefore, you can add a new location to `sys.path` like so:

```
sys.path.append('/home/USER/some/directory/')
```

where your files can be found.

Hope this helps

Comment: *it may also contain the directory which contains the project*. But that would mean there would be two different identities to objects defined in the apps: http://bugs.python.org/issue9872

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's just a matter of personal taste. I go with the directory which contains the project, but that's just my preference.

Comment: Doesn't it make the apps non-portable? I mean, in this case the apps will always need to be aware of which package they are living under, no?

Comment: If apps don't live under the project directory they need to on the sys.path to use them in the project, if you put them as modules inside of project it is enough to have the project in sys.path, also apps should never need to know in what project (project is the package) they are in in order to be portable, it's the project that should know how to find apps not other way around.

Comment: If an app wants to import stuff from the app directory without knowing the project directory, they can use the new-style `from . import modulename` syntax.  (Requires python 2.5 or higher, I think.)