# Django is unable to detect psycopg2

Tags: django, python-2.7, psycopg2

Django is unable to detect psycopg2.
I am able to import psycopg2 on python terminal.

Can you please help me as to how to proceed now?
I'm using OSX 10.10.

Comment: Any logs to be analysed ?

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @AjayGupta, no. im using postgresql db with django but while running "python manage.py migrate" , its failing with the error "ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module"
But I am able to use psycopg2 in my standalone python scripts.

Comment: are you using multiple python versions?

Comment: @AjayGupta no. python 2.7.10

Comment: When i'm doing 'import psycopg2' in terminal, im getting
'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
'

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. It had to do with a failed psycopg2 update that I absent-mindedly attempted to upgrade with pip. On Windows 7, I fixed it by manually reinstalling and adding it's location to the virtual environment's sys.path. Good luck! EDIT: see an example here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726705/django-what-is-sys-path-supposed-to-be

Comment: Found a more helpful question- this is the one that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383126/django-python-beginner-error-when-executing-python-manage-py-syncdb-psycopg2